# How do I create a desktop icon to create an Outlook note?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2016, links

In Microsoft Outlook 2016, it's possible to create notes that get stored similar to the Windows Sticky Note app.

The problem is it's inconvenient to create these notes, but they're useful because they get stored.

Is there any way to create an easy to access shortcut or link for creating Outlook Notes?

[image]

**Update:** I want to be able to create the note directly and not just open the notes section

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shortcut on the desktop using the target of:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:notes**
or
**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:notes**

(Be sure to include the quotes and spaces. You may need to change the Outlook.exe location.)

**Detailed steps:**

1. Right-click on your desktop and select New -> Shortcut
2. You'll be prompted for a target program, input the command mention above:
   [image]
   Shortcut target location:
3. Click Next to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these tricky steps to create shortcut on Desktop for "Outlook Notes"**.

[image]

- *Open Windows Explorer.*
- Browse to this folder in Windows Explorer, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15.
- Find Outlook.exe.
- Select & right click it and select Send to Desktop (create
  Shortcut).
- Go to the Desktop and right click the Outlook icon and select Properties.
- In the Target type this path,
  **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft
  Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:Notes**
- Press enter.
- From the Desktop, rename the OUTLOOK ICON to Outlook Notes.
- Finally click on it to open "Outlook Notes".

You find that Outlook now starts with the Notes window open.

Comment: Unable to understand Y this answer has been Down Voted since  it was  UP Voted earlier !!

Comment: This works, but it is easier to do it creating a new shortcut from the Windows Desktop like in Yuki Sun answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try these instead:

Notes: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.stickynote`
Tasks: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.task`
Email: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note`